# Unable to read the content I hosted in my bucket with SSL attached. Detached SSL certificate in order to see the content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here's the error message

[image: 1]

Here's the bucket policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xevlyn.com/*"
    }
]
}
```

I turned off the "Block all public access" for that bucket

Comment: What specific error are you seeing?

Comment: did you check if there is any acl in action?